# ArcMap Zonal Statistics not producing attribute table

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, spatial-analyst, zonal-statistics

I'm using the zonal statistics in spatial analyst ArcMap 10.2. The input zone is a feature (conterminous US states) and the raster (.tiff - signed integer) is biomass for the entire conterminous US. All data have been projected to albers equal area. I have selected "Ignore No Data"

The problem:Zonal Statistics does not produce an attribute table. What should I do?

Comment: Are you getting an error?  Or, does the tool complete successfully with no outputs?

Comment: The tool runs successfully, but no attribute table is created.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a screenshot of the dialog box of the Zonal Statistics as Table tool?

Comment: This question was specifically in regards to the Zonal Statistics Tool, not Zonal Statistics as Table. But I did also try the the zonal statistics as table, which did not successfully execute and I've not investigated further. I will give that another shot tomorrow. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I understand that, but the output of the Zonal Statistics tool is a raster, not an attribute table.  I think your best option is to use the Zonal Statistics as Table tool.

Comment: OK I managed to get spatial analyst as table to work. I think the raster layer is so large it has trouble running it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make one after you run the tool using the Build Raster VAT [tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0017000000m2000000). It must be integer data.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the Zonal Statistics Tool, try using the **[Zonal Statistics as Table](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Zonal_Statistics_as_Table/009z000000w8000000/)** tool.  This will create a table of the results.  You can then join this back to your Polygon layer.